# GLSL on Mobile Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 4500M card

Tags: opengl, glsl, intel

I can run openGL programs on it but does it support GLSL? looks like it doesnt, just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this card should support OpenGL 2.1... and that means that GLSL 1.2
Update the driver and maybe that will help.

Programs with GLSL 1.3 for instance will not run at all.

Answer (score 1):

Call `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);` from your program and see for yourself.